# Не работает асинхронность коментариев django-channels

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

Не могу понять почему не работает асинхронность коментариев

**cunsomer.py**

```
import json
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async
from channels.generic.websocket import  AsyncWebsocketConsumer
from comments.models import Comment
from posts.models import Post

class CommentConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):

    async def connect(self):
        self.post.id = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['post_id']
        self.post_group_name = 'post_%s' % self.post_id
        await self.channels_layer.group_add(
             self.post_group_name,
             self.channel_name
        )

        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, code):
        await self.channels_layer.discard(
        self.post_group_name,
        self.channel_name
        )

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        comment = text_data_json['text']

        new_comment = await self.create_new_comment(comment)
        data = {
        'author': new_comment.author.username,
        'created_at':new_comment.created_at.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%m'),
        'text':new_comment.text
        }

        await self.channels_layer.group_send(
           self.post_group_name,
           {
              'type':'new_comment',
              'message': data
           }
        )

    async def new_comment(self, event):
        message = event['message']
        await self.send(
        text_data=json.dumps(
        {'message': message
        })
        )

    @database_sync_to_async
    def create_new_comment(self, text):
        ct=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Post)
        new_comment = Comment.objects.create(
        author=self.scope['user'],
        text=text,
        content_type=ct,
        object_id=int(self.post_id)
        )
        return new_comment
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow! Для такого рода вопросов нужно добавлять, кроме кода, еще и ошибку или описание некоректного поведения, а также желаемое поведение... Неинформативное "почему не работает" отталкивает потенциальных отвечающих и они просто проходят мимо

Comment: ошибки нет просто не работает асинхронисть чтобы увидеть комментарий другого пользователя нужно перезагружать страницу